# Do browsers validate SSL key with CA for CORS Ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, ssl, cors

Does the iPad browser go look for CA recognition of an SSL key offered by the server during an Ajax request?

A mobile app I'm developing will use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) which means that the main page is loaded already by the time the additional resources get loaded.  As such, the Ajax requests to the server are essentially CORS over SSL.

One of the final critical issues I face in my threat assessment is how to avoid the possibility of a malicious user tricking the DNS service so that requests would go to another server and potentially upload sensitive data.  For this, I would like to know if the browser will fully validate the SSL key before sending the request?

If not, is there another way that I can be certain that my Ajax requests are going to the right place?  Other than hard-coding the IP-address into the app? (which would still leave a slight vulnerability)

Thanks!
Tyler

UPDATE:

I believe I have answered the question, and the answer is "Yes."

Wish that I could offer a definitive answer, as with a reference to the HTML specifications for XmlHTTPRequests, but instead all I have are experimental results.

I started up a PhoneGap app and was able to make a simple jQuery.ajax() request from

- https ://www.google.com/  (surprise)
- http ://www.pcwebshop.co.uk/

Both returned http status 200, etc., not surprising.

But https://www.pcwebshop.co.uk/, which has a self-signed certificate, fails and the jqXHR request object has the following:

- textStatus: 'error'
- status: 0  (not an XXX http status)
- responseText: [empty]

So it's an inductive conclusion but should work.  Still interested if anyone can answer this canonically.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be implementing HTTPS/SSL correctly if it didn't validate that the server certificate is trusted. NB 'certificate' not 'key'.